# Javascript - как правильно заполнить двумерный массив объектами?

Tags: javascript

```
    this.objectsArr = []; // Массив объектов
    this.objectsArr[0]=[]; //сделал двумерным
    this.coordsSquare = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        const width = 70;
        const height = 70;

        const x = i * 80 + 10;
        const y = j * 80 + 10;

        const square = this.generateSquare({
          x, y, width, height, i, j
        });
        this.coordsSquare.push(square);
        this.objectsArr[i,j] = square; //добавление в него
      }
    }
```

В итоге в массиве вместо 81 объекта всего 9.

Comment: так вы сделали его двумерным, почему должно 81 то получиться? В coordsSquare как раз должно 81 получиться. Ну и изящнее это все делать методами массива, сразу станет в 2 раза короче и понятнее

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так хотели?
Двумерный массив это массив массивов, а у вас массив `this.objectsArr[i,j]` - это обращение к элементу `j` массива `this.objectsArr`.
Обычно создается одномерный массив и в ячейку каждого пушится другой массив.

результат i,j от 0,0 до 8,8 Можно подсчитать там 81

```js
this.objectsArr = []; // Массив объектов

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  this.coordsSquare = new Array();
  for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    const width = 70;
    const height = 70;

    const x = i * 80 + 10;
    const y = j * 80 + 10;

    //const square = this.generateSquare({
    //  x, y, width, height, i, j
    //});
    const square = {x, y, width, height, i, j}
    this.coordsSquare.push(square);
  }
  this.objectsArr.push(coordsSquare); //добавление в него
}

console.log(objectsArr);
```

а обращение по типу a[i,j] даст значение массива a под индексом j можно посмотреть на пример

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

console.log(array[1,5])

let index = (1,5);

console.log(index)
```

Есть очень хороший пример связанный с запятой

```js
let sum = (1 + 1,5); // тут 2 операции 1 + 1 и 5
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: несколько странно называть `arr[i,j]` одномерным массивом

Comment: @teran исправил немного уточнил спс

Comment: Нет, не надо комментировать функцию, она возвращает нужные значения.

Comment: @DiscordYaz это закоментировано только что тут пример сработал. А вы можете вернуть его на место и удалить ненужную переменную